# I need to solve $\dfrac{dx}{dt}= 2x(1-0.0001x)-0.01xy, \dfrac{dy}{dt} = -0.5y+0.0001xy$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= 2\,x\,(1-0.0001\,x)-0.01\,x\,y \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= -0.5\,y+0.0001\,x\,y
\end{align}
$$
Can anyone tell how do we solve such problems, if there is some general approach.

If anyone can tell the answer too, that will be helpful, so that i can check myself

EDIT : I did what calude said, it looks like it cannot be solved by hand.

I tried using wolfram it says time up.

If anyone with matlab or mathematica can help, I will be grateful

Comment: It may be possible to find an approximate solution.  Do you have particular initial conditions?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Extract $y$ from the first equation and replace in the second. You will obtain a second order differential equation for $x$ (probaly not very nice). Solve it (if feasible) and, from $x$, compute $y$ from the first step.

Comment: yes I do, $x = 1000, y=200, t=0$

Answer (score 0):

*(Too long for a comment.)*

Initially I thought this could be approached as a perturbation problem by letting $\epsilon = 1/100$ and writing your equations as

$$
\begin{align}
x' &= 2 x (1-\epsilon^2 x) - \epsilon x y, \\
y' &= -\frac{1}{2} y + \epsilon^2 x y,
\end{align}
$$

$$
x(0) = \frac{10}{\epsilon^2}, \quad y(0) = \frac{2}{\epsilon}.
$$

However it turns out the natural scaling $x = X/\epsilon^2$, $y = Y/\epsilon$ transforms your system into

$$
\begin{align}
X' &= 2 X (1-X) - X Y, \\
Y' &= -\frac{1}{2} Y + X Y,
\end{align}
$$

$$
X(0) = 10, \quad Y(0) = 2,
$$

thus removing all the extreme constants.  It's possible to show that $\bigl(X(t), Y(t)\bigr) \to (1/2,1)$ as $t \to \infty$, but beyond this it seems like a numerical approach would be your best bet.